# GitLab RSA key doesn't work

Tags: git, ssh, rsa, gitlab

We have our own GitLab server on local linux machine and we want to use SSH. HTTP works fine but when I generate SSH-RSA key, it doesn't work (access denied).

Installation of git is with plink. RSA key is generated with puttygen and private key is added to Pageant. Public key is coppied into profile in GitLab profile section. But everytime i want to clone repository, it says access denied :( When i use DSA key in putty gen, then it works. But i want to use RSA because i want to use gerrit (and its replication plugin) and in gerrit DSA key doesn't work (don't know why :/)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your `vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. does your rsa key exists or have you tried adding your key to the list of your `authoirzed_keys` file?

Comment: No, but why DSA is working without this setting?

Comment: The GitLab's module who manage SSH is `gitlab-shell`. Check the conf file for this module (in a gitlab omnibus install: `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/config.yml`) and check the line which looks like `auth_file: "/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys"`. Check this file exists and check GitLab has the correct read/write access level to this file